# diff two files ignoring some parts of the lines

Tags: debugging, diff, bytecode, meld

Let's say I have two files produced from `javap -v`.

output will look something like this:

```
   [...]
   299: astore        15
   301: aload         15
   303: aload         18
   305: if_acmpeq     367
   308: aload         15
   310: arraylength
   311: istore        17
   313: iload         17
   315: ifeq          348
   318: aload         15
   320: iconst_2
   321: laload
   322: lstore        19
   324: aload_1
   325: getfield      #49                 // Field my/somewhere/Some.thing:J
   328: lstore        21
   330: lload         19
   332: lload         21
   334: land
   335: lstore        19

   [...]
```

If I diff this with another file, most of the linenumbers will have changed and show up as a "difference".

I COULD write a sript that removes them, but I still need them to see where my code is jumping to.

Similarly, that field `/ Field my/somewhere/Some.thing:J` happens to have `#49` is completely irrelevant.

At the same time, a changed register *is* relevant.

So is there a tool (preferably with a GUI, of course, as the files are quite large and context is helpful in figuring out what is going on) to diff two files while ignoring parts of the line without removing said parts?

The line number, at least. Could be as simple as "ignore everything up to the first `:`.

Ideally, of course, it would allow me to set more sophisticated exclusion checks, like "ignore integers if they are marked with an `#` or follow a word on the same line that is prefixed with either `if`, `jsr` or `goto`. But I don't expect there to be something as convenient.

**UPDATE**

Using [asmtools jdis](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/CodeTools/asmtools) as suggested by @user882813 will result in an output like

```
        astore  6;
        aload   6;
        aload   8;
        if_acmpeq   L795;
        aload   6;
        arraylength;
        istore  7;
        iload   7;
        ifeq    L781;
        aload   6;
        iload   4;
        laload;
        lstore  9;
        aload_1;
        getfield    Field my/somehwere/Some.thing:"J";
        lstore  11;
        lload   9;
        lload   11;
        land;
        lstore  9;

        ...

L795:   stack_frame_type full;
        locals_map ...
```

Which is a LOT better for diffing than the `javap -v` output.
(And personally, I quite like the inlined `locals_map` and `stack_map`.)

Still, the jump targets / labels (e.g. `L795`) all show up as false positives.

Additionally, the same now goes for try-catch block labels (e.g. `t6`).

```
        try t6;
        aload   4;
        getfield    Field Something.f:"Lparc/lang/Foo;";
        checkcast   class SpecialFoo;
        endtry t6;
        goto    L495;
        catch t6 java/lang/ClassCastException;
        stack_frame_type full;
        locals_map class Something, class parc/some/Thing, bogus, int, class Something$1, class SpecialFoo, class "[J", bogus, class "[J", bogus, bogus, bogus, bogus, null, null;
        stack_map class java/lang/ClassCastException;
        new class java/lang/Error;
        dup;
        ldc String "not SpecialFoo";
        invokespecial   Method java/lang/Error."<init>":"(Ljava/lang/String;)V";
        athrow;
L495:   stack_frame_type stack1;
        stack_map class SpecialFoo;
        nop;
```

So it would still be convenient if the tool could be configured to ignore the `t<integer>` and `L<integer>` parts of the lines.

Comment: So to clarify the question, what you want is a diff that ignores constant pool indices and bytecode offsets?

Comment: I have a class library for C# that you could use to write your own diffing tool - [DiffLib](https://github.com/lassevk/DiffLib), but of course, replacing Meld or any other visual tool will be a huge undertaking. I know Beyond Compare has the functionality to do what you ask, you sure Meld doesn't have anything hidden in there? I think it's called "Rules" in BC.

Comment: @Antimony Indeed.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen if Meld does have the capabilities to do what I want, then I have not yet found the necessary configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [asmtools jdis](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/CodeTools/asmtools) instead of `javap`.
`asmtools jdis` has more clean output.

For example, for simple HelloWorld application

```
class Hello {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, world!");
  }
}
```

`asmtools jdis` output will be:

```
super class Hello
    version 52:0
{


Method "<init>":"()V"
    stack 1 locals 1
{
        aload_0;
        invokespecial   Method java/lang/Object."<init>":"()V";
        return;
}

public static varargs Method main:"([Ljava/lang/String;)V"
    stack 2 locals 1
{
        getstatic   Field java/lang/System.out:"Ljava/io/PrintStream;";
        ldc String "Hello, world!";
        invokevirtual   Method java/io/PrintStream.println:"(Ljava/lang/String;)V";
        return;
}

} // end Class Hello
```

JFYI, numbers in the front of instructions is not line numbers but bytecode instruction offsets.

Comment: Immensely helpful, thanks a lot! Of course it doesn't get rid of the false positives for jump targets, and it does insert new labels for try-catch blocks, so I'll keep this question open, for now, But I very much appreciate your answer.